# Have you ever told someone they look nice when you really don't mean it?

Tags: present-perfect

> Have you ever told someone they **look** nice when you really **don't** mean it?

According to a native speaker, this sentence is fine and common. Why is this sentence OK and common?

I think the tenses don't match. "Have you ever..." refers to a period from your childhood up to now. "They look nice when you really don't mean it" refers to now. The time intervals just partially overlap.

I would think the following sentence is the only correct one.

> Have you ever told someone they **looked** nice when you really **didn't** mean it?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're unsure about. Did you expect different grammar, perhaps: "*they look**ed** nice when you really **didn't** mean it*"? If so, please edit your question and say this directly.

Comment: I would certainly expect "didn't" rather than "don't"

Answer (score 2):

You are right that the tenses in the that-clause are incorrect: that said, it doesn't seem unnatural to me.

Grammar rules for speech are somewhat more relaxed than for writing: as long as it's not ambiguous, and it doesn't sound completely wrong, not many people would notice. As this [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=told%20her%20that%20she%20looks%20%2Ctold%20her%20that%20she%20looked&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctold%20her%20that%20she%20looks%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctold%20her%20that%20she%20looked%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctold%20her%20that%20she%20looks%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctold%20her%20that%20she%20looked%3B%2Cc0) shows, the simple present form is used occasionally in writing (where the rules are stricter) though the past simple form is a lot more common.

Comment: Stephen, you asked a question yesterday about sentences of this type, and I told you that I personally would use the past tense. I deliberately didn't say that you shouldn't use the present tense because, like JavaLatte, I had a feeling that people do use it informally.